# How to stream a device camera in Ionic/Angular and use it with tensorflowjs for face recognition?

Tags: angular, tensorflow, ionic-framework, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use the device camera from IOS/Android. I wish to obtain the video stream and pass it to tensorflow and detect faces. I have achieve this in windows using python+opencv+tensorflow. Now I want to achieve the same for ios/android using ionic/angular. Any suggestions of how can this be achieve ?

terminal.page.ts:

```
async detectFromVideo(video) {
      const results = await this.detect(video);
      const canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement;
      this.canvas.nativeElement.width = this.video.nativeElement.videoWidth;
      this.canvas.nativeElement.height = this.video.nativeElement.videoHeight;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      for (const bboxInfo of results) {
          const bbox = bboxInfo[0];
          const classID = bboxInfo[1];
          const score = bboxInfo[2];

          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineWidth = '4';
          if (classID === 0) {
              ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
              ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
          } else {
              ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
              ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
          }

          ctx.rect(bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2] - bbox[0], bbox[3] - bbox[1]);
          ctx.stroke();

          ctx.font = '30px Arial';

          const content = this.id2class[classID] + ' ' + score.toFixed(2);
          ctx.fillText(content, bbox[0], bbox[1] < 20 ? bbox[1] + 30 : bbox[1] - 5);
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          this.detectFromVideo(video);
      });
  }
```

terminal.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Terminal Page</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid >
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-icon color="success" name="thermometer-outline"></ion-icon>
        <span>35 F/C</span>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-card class="">
    <ion-card-content class="card-success">
      <img [src]="currentImage">
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-button (click)="takeSnap()">Snapshot</ion-button>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please could you show what have you tried ?

Comment: Please check my question again I just added the code. What I am trying right now is to take a snapshot of te current "frame"  with a interval from rxjs but of course this is a very expensive/slow operation. But the idea is to pass the video stream from the camera. @edkeveked

Comment: You can also use `tf.data.webcam` to capture the data of the camera iteratively

Comment: can this work with androi/ios builtin camera? I have not test but I gess this works with browser/webapps cameras @edkeveked

Comment: You can give it a try and see

Comment: @edkeveked Found this is the source code: " Create an iterator that generate `Tensor`s from webcam video stream. This API
 * only works in Browser environment when the device has webcam.
 *"

Answer (score 2):

By using `interval(1)` a video is captured each millisecond, which means that 60000 frames/s. That's a lot. A video is generally around 20 frames/s.

To capture at each second:

```
interval(1000)
```

Instead of setting a hard coded interval of time at which to capture the frame, it is better to use `requestAnimationFrame` so that the browser can capture the frame when ready.

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  takeSnap()
}

takeSnap() {
   this.cameraPreview.takeSnapshot({quality: 85}).then((data) => {
      this.currentImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
      requestAnimationFrame(takeSnap)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: sure that was only for testing and  yes I am using requestAnimationFrame... I already succeed to pass video frames an process it in real time with tensorflowjs  :D but only in the browser as I mentioned before... by the way it can be done both ways with the navigator or with tf.data.webcam but on mobile devices you need native access which why I need ionic... so still this does not answer my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. `requestAnimationFrame` works on mobile devices. The answer is not using `tf.data.webcam`. You simply need to take the snapshot of the video when `requestAnimationFrame` is called

Comment: Sure requestAnimationframe works in mobile so please show me an example of how can you access a mobile device front or rear camera in a browser or app without using a plugin like from cordova or capacitor or phonegap or similar.

Comment: Even with requestAnimationFrame, you still need to use the mobile built-in camera. `requestAnimationFrame` changes just how much often you will call `takeSnap`

Comment: Yes that was my main question how to access the built in camera and get frames/stream in ionic with capacitor or cordova not requestAnimationFrame

Comment: and why don't you want to use `requestAnimationFrame` ? Well, if you don't want to use it, you just have to set the appropriate time interval. Capturing a frame each millisecond is too costly and pointless

Comment: Please check the updated code.As I told you I am using requestAnimationFrame, this function will work properly on browsers because the stream can be obtained from getUserMedia but now I need to impllment it using native camera using ionic/capacitor or cordova....